# PUT a reportUnit through REST fails - Tomcat error

Tags: http, tomcat, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I don't know how to solve this issue. This is my request, I changed the formatting so the Content-Length is not correct in this sample:

```
PUT /jasperserver/rest/resource/reports/Customers/3221/Wasser1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.84.6.166:8080
Accept: */*
Cookie: JSESSIONID=D170F2EA5110E4ADA55515C8F1B4D68F
X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT
Content-Length: 1697

<resourcedescriptor isnew="true" name="Wasser1" uristring="/reports/Customers/3221/Wasser1" wstype="reportUnit">
<label>
<!--[CDATA[test_report(test.jrxml)]]-->
</label>
<description>
<!--[CDATA[Wasser1 generated by Jasper.php through REST Mon, 15 Jul 2013 09:57:56 +0200]]-->
</description>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[/reports/Customers/3221]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_HAS_DATA">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[false]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_IS_REFERENCE">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[false]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.jasperreports.domain.ReportUnit]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_RU_ALWAYS_PROPMT_CONTROLS">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[false]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_RU_CONTROLS_LAYOUT">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[1]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourcedescriptor isnew="false" name="test02" uristring="/reports/Customers/3221/test02" wstype="jrxml">
<label>
<!--[CDATA[test02 Report]]-->
</label>
<description>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[/reports/Customers/3221]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_HAS_DATA">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[true]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_IS_REFERENCE">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[false]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.domain.FileResource]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
<resourceproperty name="PROP_SECURITY_PERMISSION_MASK">
<value>
<!--[CDATA[31]]-->
</value>
</resourceproperty>
</description>
</resourcedescriptor>
</resourcedescriptor>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you have X-HTTP-Method-Override on the request?

Comment: I've read that it's better to add that line for compatibility reason in all REST/PUT requests.

Comment: You shouldn't believe all you read :-)

Comment: unknown headers are ignored by the httpd, some servers don't allow `PUT` so you need `POST` in combination with the override header, google it, you'll find many issues regarding this

Comment: Yes, but there's no point whatsover to add X-HTTP-Method-Override when your method already is PUT.

Also, what *server* supports X-HTTP-Method-Override but does not support PUT? I think you are confusing servers with broken clients/libraries/middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that child ResourceDescriptors are references to themselves,

so I had to add:

```
PROP_RU_IS_REFERENCE = true
PROP_RU_REFERENCE_URI = uriString
```

for it to work!